# How to apply VBA code that moves columns down to all sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to apply this VBA code to all sheets, to no avail:

```
    Sub MoveColsDown()
' MovetoA16 Macro
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Range("A1:I1171").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("A16:I1186")
Next

End Sub
```

Essentially, I'm trying to select all the content in a sheet and move it down so that the top left corner of the data is now in A16, not A1.

There is probably a better way for me to be selecting all data, too? For now, I just specified a range that is far bigger than the space any of the data would ever occupy.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. If there were a way to exclude certain sheets from having this process applied to it, I'd love to learn... e.g. a sheet titled 'Dashboard'.

Answer (score 4):

Just insert 15 rows at the top of the worksheet.

```
Sub MoveColsDown()

    dim sh as worksheet
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        if sh.name <> "Dashboard" then
            sh.Range("1:15").entirerow.insert
        end if
    Next sh

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just qualify the ranges:

```
Sub MoveColsDown()
' MovetoA16 Macro
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        sh.Range("A1:I1171").Cut Destination:=sh.Range("A16:I1186")
    Next

End Sub
```

NOTE:

We don't need the `Select`.